# Finding all users that have the same security role groups in common

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008 SP4

I am trying to examine the data and determine all the users that have a common collection of security roles. For a match they much have identically the same collection of security roles. Example data

Table **User_Roles**:

```
UserID RoleID
------ ------
User1  Role1
User1  Role2
User1  Role3
User2  Role1
User3  Role3
User4  Role1
User4  Role2
User4  Role3
User5  Role1
User6  Role3
User7  Role1
```

Results set should return those that have the same grouped collection

```
User1, User4    -- users with ROLE1,2&3
User2, User5, User7   -- users with ROLE1 ONLY
User3, User6  -- users with ROLE3 ONLY
```

Comment: hint - use STUFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using STUFF

step 1: Group the Roles (in order) per User by way of STUFFing Roles 
step 2: STUFF Users per Grouped Roles

```
declare @users table
(userID varchar(10), roleID varchar(10))

insert into @users
values ('User1','Role1'),
('User1','Role2'),
('User1','Role3'),
('User2','Role1'),
('User3','Role3'),
('User4','Role1'),
('User4','Role2'),
('User4','Role3'),
('User5','Role1'),
('User6','Role3'),
('User7','Role1')


-- group data according to role as the base table or you can dump this to a temp table
select y.userid, stuff((select ',' + roleid
            from @users x
           where x.userID = y.userID 
           order by x.roleID     --- need to order by so it won't in random order
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')  as GroupRole

from @users y
group by y.userID

-- New structure 

userid  GroupRole
User1   Role1,Role2,Role3
User2   Role1
User3   Role3
User4   Role1,Role2,Role3
User5   Role1
User6   Role3
User7   Role1


-- OFFICIAL QUERY  (not using temp tables otherwise reformat accordingly)

select stuff((select ',' + g.userID

    from (select y.userid, stuff((select ',' + roleid       --- can substitute with temp table
            from @users x
           where x.userID = y.userID 
           order by x.roleID
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')  as GroupRole
    from @users y
    group by y.userID ) g
    where g.GroupRole = a.GroupRole        --- group matched from main query
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')  as Result

from   --- reference table as bases of the grouping, can substitute with temp table
(select y.userid, stuff((select ',' + roleid
            from @users x
           where x.userID = y.userID 
           order by x.roleID
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')  as GroupRole
    from @users y
    group by y.userID ) a
group by a.GroupRole   


Result --
User2,User5,User7
User1,User4
User3,User6
```

Comment: This gives me exactly what I needed. Perfect thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with set-based operations:

```
with ur as (
      select ur.*, count(*) over (partition by userid) as cnt
      from user_roles ur
     )
select ur1.userid, ur2.userid
from ur ur1 join
     ur ur2
     on ur1.roleid = ur2.roleid and
        ur1.cnt = ur2.cnt and
        ur1.userid < ur2.userid
group by ur1.userid, ur2.userid, ur1.cnt
having count(*) = ur1.cnt;
```

This checks that all the roles match between two users and that they have the same number of roles.

Comment: this is just the first part.. to finish this will then be STUFFing them relatively

Comment: Gordon this also work for me. The answer above just presented the data in a slightly better format for what I needed. Thanks for your help. This is a very clean solution.